# Save an array as bin in Matlab, pass it to Python and read the bin file in Python

Tags: python, matlab

I am currently trying to save an array as bin file in Matlab, send it to Python and read it in Python. However, Matlab is showing errors when I run it. I am using the following codes:

Read the array in Matlab, convert to bin file and pass to Python:

```
array1 = rand(5,1); %% array1 is the desired array that needs to be sent to Python

fid = fopen('nazmul.bin','wb'); %% I want to save array1 in the nazmul.bin file

fwrite(fid,array1);

status=fclose(fid);

python('squared.py','nazmul.bin'); %% I want to send the parameters to squared.py program
```

squared.py file:

```
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
f = open("nazmul.bin", "rb")   # Trying to open the bin file

try:

   byte = f.read(1)       # Reading the bin file and saving it in the byte array

   while byte != "":

   # Do stuff with byte.

       byte = f.read(1)

   finally:

       f.close()

   print byte                # printing the byte array from Python
```

However, when I run this program, nothing gets printed. I guess that the bin file is not getting passed properly to the squared.py file.

Thanks for your feedback.

Nazmul

Comment: I am using the proper format in if name == 'main'. But it's not appearing properly in the question.

Comment: In your python script, you're hardcoding the name 'nazmul.bin', so passing a value is not necessary.  What happens if you try running it without passing a value?

Comment: Also, matlab might not be writing to the same path that python is reading from.  If this is the case, you should specify the path in one or both of your scripts.

Answer (score 4):

There are several problems here.

1. You should use double underscore when checking for 'main'. I.e. `__main__ == "__main__"`.
2. You are *not* collecting bytes but rather always storing the *last* byte read. Therefore, the last byte is always `""`.
3. Finally, it seems like indentation is not correct. I assume this is just a stackoverflow formatting error.
4. One more potential issue - When you use fwrite(fid, A) in MATLAB, it assumes that you want to write bytes (8 bit numbers). However, your `rand()` command generates reals, so MATLAB first rounds the results to integers and your binary file will hold '0' or '1' only.

Final note: Reading a file one byte at a time is probably very inefficient. It is probably better to read the file in large chunks, or - if it is a small file - read the entire file in one `read()` operation.

The corrected Python code is as follows:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
   f = open("xxx.bin", "rb")   # Trying to open the bin file

   try:
     a = [];
     byte = f.read(1)       # Reading the bin file and saving it in the byte array
     while byte != "":
       a.append(byte);
       # Do stuff with byte.
       byte = f.read(1)

   finally:
       f.close()

   print a;
```